# Unicode error Ordinal not in range

Tags: python, unicode

Odd error with unicode for me. I was dealing with unicode fine, but when I ran it this morning one item u'\u201d' gave error and gives me

```
UnicodeError: ASCII encoding error: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I looked up the code and apparently its utf-32 but when I try to decode it in the interpreter:

```
c = u'\u201d'
c.decode('utf-32', 'replace')
```

Or any other operation with it for that matter, it just doesnt recognize it in any codec but yet I found it as "RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK"

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#154>", line 1, in <module>
    c.decode('utf-32')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_32.py", line 11, in decode
    return codecs.utf_32_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u201d' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You already have a unicode string, there is no need to decode it to a unicode string *again*.

What happens in that case is that python helpfully tries to first *encode* it for you, so that you can then decode it from `utf-32`. It uses the default encoding to do so, which happens to be ASCII. Here is an explicit encode to show you the exception raised in that case:

```
>>> u'\u201d'.encode('ASCII')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u201d' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

In short, when you have a unicode literal like `u''`, there is no need to decode it.

Read up on the unicode, encodings, and default settings in the [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html). Another invaluable article on the subject is Joel Spolsky's [Minimun Unicode knowledge](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) post.

Comment: Great article about unicode knowledge, I was definitely one of those hoping for the best haha, but I still cant make that specific code appear!

Comment: @Kos: It works for some of the pseudo-codecs like `u'FF'.decode('hex')`

Comment: @rodling: How are you trying to output it? You'll need to *encode* unicode values for display or saving to a file.

Comment: c.encode('utf-32', 'replace')
Output is:
'\xff\xfe\x00\x00\x1d \x00\x00'

Comment: @rodling: UTF-32 can cover any character; that looks like perfectly valid UTF-32 (including the BOM).

Comment: So any ideas how to display it? I am having a brain fart with this, all my unicode was dealt find in the past and now this...

Comment: You didn't tell me *at all* where you are trying to display this. If it is in your terminal, in HTML output, in a GUI app, or anything.

Comment: Sorry, I am writing analysing it and then writing it to file. But it should be configured for GUI

Comment: @rodling: That is far from enough context, and we are truly straining the comments to breaking point here. Perhaps you should create a new question *with detailed context* and what happens.